# Can translocation occur within a gene?

Tags: dna, dna-replication

I know genes can be translocated between chromosomes but can nucleotide sequences be moved around within an individual gene?

Could the following gene:
MEN SAW OLD HEN

Become:
MSA WOL DHE NEN

By moving the EN at the beginning to the end?